# How to interpret values returned by numpy.ndarray.item() when downcasting floats

Tags: python, numpy, casting, floating-point

I work with spatial data and often have coordinates that require, at most, precision to only a few decimal places, e.g. `89.995`.

A simple example:

```py
import numpy as np


arr = np.array([89.995])
```

Inspect the dtypes:

```py
>>> y.dtype
dtype('float64')

>>> arr[0]
-89.995  # This is what I need. Good.
```

But for my purposes, I often work with large gridded data where I don't need the precision of 64-bit floats, so I'd like to downcast coordinate values to `float32` or, ideally, `float16` to reduce memory load. However, after downcasting, when inspecting the items I see precision issues that don't exist in `float64`, despite the values being far from exceeding the precision limits of `float32`.

E.g.

```py
>>> arr[0].item()
-89.995

>>> arr[0].astype(np.float32).item()
-89.99500274658203
```

I need coordinates to be exact. Since I'm primarily working within a `numpy` context, should I care about this? Are they functionally the same value (and I'm just misunderstanding how `item()` works?), or is there actually a fundamental difference between the two values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The number -89.995 cannot be represented exactly in binary. The number *actually* stored as a float64 is -89.9950000000000045474735088646411895751953125.
2. When printing the number, Python "cheats" a bit, and prints a minimal-length digit string that would convert back to the same number. Thus, it prints `-89.995`, even though that is not the number actually stored.
3. When you convert to float32, you lose 29 bits of significand, meaning that the number actually stored is now even more different from -89.995.
4. When you do `.item()`, the float32 gets converted back to a "native" Python float, which is always a float64.
5. This float64 number is *not* the same number that you would get from converting the digit string `-89.995` and, hence, gets printed differently.

So, -89.995 and the number you are seeing are the same number, in the sense that they map to the same bit pattern as a float32.

We can test this using the `struct` module:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('>f', -89.995)
b'\xc2\xb3\xfdq'
>>> struct.pack('>f', -89.99500274658203)
b'\xc2\xb3\xfdq'
```

Answer (score 1):

[floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) are rarely exact, they represent an approximation due to the way that those numbers are stored in a computer's memory (as a sum of powers of 2).

So, the first think is: your number will almost never be exact for a long enough precision.

Python floats use 64 bits, thus `89.995` is in fact:

```
from decimal import Decimal

Decimal(arr[0].item())
# Decimal('89.9950000000000045474735088646411895751953125')
```

When converting to 32 bits you actually lose precision:

```
Decimal(arr[0].astype(np.float32).item())
# Decimal('89.99500274658203125')
```

You should probably `round` your number to the desired precision:

```
round(arr[0].item(), 3)
# 89.995
```

Comment: @Sam I had changed "never" to "almost never" in my second statement but forgot to fix the first sentence. Indeed, some numbers can have an exact representation. I updated. Thank you!